# Breaking down of complex sentence

Tags: translation

1. ガラス窓のこちら、レジの内側に坐って、見るともなしに赤いアウディを眺めていた喜一は思わずそう呟つぶやいた。
2. 運転席の男の話にしばらく頷いたり首を傾げたりしていたアルバイトが、困った顔になって喜一の方を見たからだった。

a) In the first sentence, 見るともなしに赤いアウディを眺めていた, I suppose it means looking at the red car without looking, but doesn't this sound illogical?

b) In the second sentence, 運転席の男の話にしばらく頷いたり首を傾げたりしていたアルバイトが, I am confused by this phrase, does it mean nods and tilts one's head towards the words spoken by the man in the driver's seat? Then what does アルバイト mean here? Seems アルバイト can't fit in this context.

c) 困った顔になって喜一の方を見たからだった。Does it mean because he saw the troubled face of 喜一?

Comment: Please try to ask one question per question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a) In the first sentence, 見{み}るともなしに赤{あか}いアウディを眺{なが}めていた, I suppose it means looking at the red car without looking, but doesn't this sound illogical?

It is logical and natural-sounding.  We even say 「見るともなく見る」, which I am sure will drive you up the wall.

「見る」, in this context, means "***to look hard***", "***to look with an intention***", "***to really watch***", etc.

「眺める」, however, means "***to gaze casually (without an intention of any sort)***".

That is why you can 眺める an object without really/seriously 見るing it.

> "喜一, who was gazing at the red Audi without really watching it, murmured ~~~"

Hope this sounds logical to you as well.

> b) In the second sentence, 運転席の男の話にしばらく頷いたり首を傾げたりしていたアルバイトが, I am confused by this phrase, does it mean nods and tilts one's head towards the words spoken by the man in the driver's seat? Then what does アルバイト mean here? Seems アルバイト can't fit in this context.

Again, the phrase makes perfect sense.  Here is why.

「アルバイト」 here means a "***part-time worker***"; It refers to a person and **not** a job/position.  I suspect this is where you made a mistake.  Why would professional authors just throw in words that do not fit in the context in any language/culture?

> "(It was because) the part-time employee who had been nodding and tilting his head towards the words spoken by the man in the driver's seat ~~~~"

Finally,

> c) 困った顔になって喜一の方を見たからだった。Does it mean because he saw the troubled face of 喜一?

No, it does not.  It is the part-time employee (with a troubled face) who looked in the direction of 喜一.